# Исключение dispatchUncaughtException

Tags: java, исключения, openstreetmap

Класс обращается к OpenStreetMap для того что бы узнать координаты переданного города.
Например при передачи

```
location = 'london'
```

возвращает

```
lat="51.5073219" lon="-0.1276474"
```

В случае если передаю

```
location = 'Manchester, UK'
```

возникает вот такое исключение:

```
Tread.dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable)
```

Не могу понять что не так.
 Вот код:

```
protected List<String> getParameters(String location) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    List<String> elemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        String url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q="+ location +"&format=xml";
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());
        Element rootElem = doc.getDocumentElement();

        NodeList nList = rootElem.getElementsByTagName("place");
        Element attrElem = (Element) nList.item(0);

        elemList.add(attrElem.getAttribute("lat"));
        elemList.add(attrElem.getAttribute("lon"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return elemList;
}
```

Comment: Не знаю как java с url работает, но на всякий случай попробуйте убрать пробел, например, заменить его на `%20`. Т.е. чтобы `location` был равен `Manchester,%20UK`. Либо вообще пробел уберите: `Manchester,UK`

Comment: Да помогло. Спасибо.
Просто если передать такой запрос напрямую в броузер то он сам заменяет пробелы я думал что тут так же будет сам менять.

Comment: Читайте [доки](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html): `The URL class does not itself encode or decode any URL components according to the escaping mechanism defined in RFC2396. It is the responsibility of the caller to encode any fields, which need to be escaped prior to calling URL, and also to decode any escaped fields, that are returned from URL. Furthermore, because URL has no knowledge of URL escaping, it does not recognise equivalence between the encoded or decoded form of the same URL`

Comment: @BOPOH скопируйте ваш коммент в форму ответа...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [RFC2396](http://www.w3.org/2002/11/dbooth-names/rfc2396-numbered_clean.htm), пробелы не являются частью валидного URI:

> > 2.4.3. Excluded US-ASCII Characters
> >
> > ...The space character is excluded because significant spaces may disappear and insignificant spaces may be introduced when URI are transcribed or typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs.  Whitespace is also used to delimit URI in many contexts.

При этом вы формируете url, который содержит пробел из-за `Manchester, UK`.

Браузеры согласно этому RFC преобразуют пробелы в последовательность `%20`, но [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) этого не делает:

> > The URL class does not itself encode or decode any URL components according to the escaping mechanism defined in RFC2396. It is the responsibility of the caller to encode any fields, which need to be escaped prior to calling URL, and also to decode any escaped fields, that are returned from URL. Furthermore, because URL has no knowledge of URL escaping, it does not recognise equivalence between the encoded or decoded form of the same URL. For example, the two URLs:
> >
> > http://foo.com/hello world/ and http://foo.com/hello%20world
> >
> > would be considered not equal to each other.

Таким образом надо либо самому экранировать пробел:

```
location = 'Manchester,%20UK'
```

либо вообще убрать его (сработает в вашем случае, но в общем так делать не стоит):

```
location = 'Manchester,UK',
```

либо использовать какие-либо инструменты для обертки, например:

```
URI searchUri = new URI(
    "http",
    null,
    "nominatim.openstreetmap.org",
    80,
    "/search",
    "q="+ location +"&format=xml",
    null);
URL searchUrl = searchUri.toURL();
```

тогда метод будет работать как ожидается